# Could use an explanation of the notation for an oracle adversary

Tags: pseudo-random-function, decryption-oracle

In the definition below, what exactly does it mean for the adversary (not even sure that's the correct term?) to equal one?

$$
\underset{K}{Pr} \left [A^{F_k(\cdot)} = 1 \right ] 
$$

[Source](http://www.csc.kth.se/utbildning/kth/kurser/DD2448/krypto13/handouts/lec03.pdf) (Page 22/35?)

> [image]

Comment: Asymptotic security definitions ARGHHH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This represents the probability over all $K$ that $A$ given an oracle access to $F_K(\cdot)$ outputs 1. You usually compare that to the probability of A ouptputting 1 while having oracle access to a random function and the difference tells you how well $A$ does at telling $F_K$ from random